# Check if my iframe is in a Facebook document?

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, facebook-apps

I have created a Facebook app to house my site within an iframe.

At every request I want to check that the site is inside the Facebook app, otherwise I want to redirect the user to the Facebook app.

I can check that I am within an iframe with javascript:

if (top != self)

But I don't know if I'm actually inside the Facebook app.
The cross-domain security hinders me from accessing the parent document's info. For example, "top.location.href" cannot be accessed.

Can someone help me out? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Facebook attaches a value to window.name so you can use JavaScript to check.

```
if(window.name.indexOf('iframe_canvas_fb') != -1){
  // in Facebook
} else {
  // not in Facebook
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check FB.Canvas namespace methods from facebook's javascript library. It will work on Facebook canvas.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/
```

check what info do you get while in the facebook's iframe, outside iframe or in another iframe.

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Well if the user is outside of Facebook this bit of script before the body html tag should redirect them back to your page on Facebook:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (self == top) {
    window.location = "http://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_PAGE";
}
-->
</script>
```

remember to change the 'YOUR_APP_PAGE' bit to something like:
'my-application?app_data=page-location'

you can send the request ?app_data to your Facebook page using php and append the page that your website was redirected from so that the app_data can tell your app to load this page but within Facebook.

So it is worth looking up Facebook app_data

If you want to change the style of your page depending if it is displayed on Facebook or not then use this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (window.self = "http://apps.facebook.com/") {
    var element = document.getElementById('html');
    element.className = "facebook"; 
}
-->
</script>
```

and modify your html tag with the id=html like so:

```
<html id="html" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

this will allow you to use a class name .facebook remap any style for your page that you like.

If you need to set some initial php settings like the redirect page, then you can use this code in php to detect if you are within Facebook, however this code can not detect if the user is on Facebook or not after they have logged in:

```
if(!empty($_POST['signed_request'])){
//do something with php here...
}
```

Note:

It is unlikely the Facebook user on your app page has JavaScript turned off which is why we can use the above php code to set redirects etc...

php should not really rely on $_SESSION or cookies for this in case the user decides to visit your page having logged in to your Facebook application, it would take a page refresh for php to determine that they are no longer in Facebook from the session or cookie.

After thought:

All this information should be on the Facebook SDK's as managing redirects and application detection is a nightmare with Facebook's horrific documentation.

Hope this helps you out :)

Comment: if (window.self = "http://apps.facebook.com/") {

seems definitely wrong as its no comparison. But even after using == it wont work.